# client side confirmation popup in html quickform

Tags: php, javascript

I am using html quickforms and php. I have a form. When a field value exceeds 200  and he clicks submit i want to show a popup confirmation box, how do i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need JavaScript for popup confirmation box.

something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/adG6y/):

html:

```
<input type='text' name='data' id='data' />
<div id='click' onclick="checkVal();">Click Me</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkVal() {
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById('data').value, 10) > 200) alert('exeeds 200');
}
```